# For what value of n this inequality is true and how to find it step by step?

Tags: inequality

The inequality is 
$1000n^3<2^n$
I'm trying to see for what value of $n$ an algorithm A who takes ($1000n^3$) steps takes less time than another algorithm B who takes($2^n$) steps.

Any idea how to do that step by step?

Comment: Take logarithm on both sides.

Comment: I don't know how in this specific case

Comment: ... then compare the curves of $f(x)=\log(1000)+3\log(x)$ and  $g(x)=x \log(2)$, which is easier that the intial curves. They intersect at a certain value $x_0$. Round it at the closest integer which is n=24.